# buildozer apk closes once opened and gives me alot of information about my phone

Tags: python, android, kivy, logcat, buildozer

I'm trying to make an android app with buildozer and when I run `buildozer -v android debug run logcat` the app opens then closes immediatly and the logcat just gives me alot of useless information about my phone. It's too much that I can't copy it all. I think it just lists my apps and notifications but I don't know why. This happened when I wanted to integrate fingerprint scanners in my app I used [this github repo](https://github.com/tito/fingerprint) but I removed `import org.fingerprint.FingerprintCallbackInterface;` from FingerprintCallback.java because it kept telling me that org.fingerprint doesn't exist so is there a solution for this? thanks in advance

Here is a part of it:

```
02-11 15:55:20.520 17978 17978 I NeoBean_Util: isEmulator() : false
02-11 15:55:20.520 17978 17978 I NeoBean_NotificationListener: onNotificationPosted():: Not connected
02-11 15:55:20.520 11349 11349 I WearableDeviceFactory: getDeviceManager() deviceID = ##:##:##:##:51:93 mDeviceManagerList = {##:##:##:##:51:93=com.samsung.android.hostmanager.manager.GearDeviceManager@3270048}
02-11 15:55:20.520 11349 11349 W Notification4R_GO: PackageUtil.checkIgnoreCase-On-Going,[kz.sirius.siriuschat]
02-11 15:55:20.521  8650 17081 I System.out:  ===> https://sirius-1.gps-watch.kz/
02-11 15:55:20.521  8650 17081 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
02-11 15:55:20.521  8650 17081 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
02-11 15:55:20.523  8650 17081 I System.out: {"imei":"HTTP_813c7084-71f3-4577-a78c-c713ca21fd3b","firmware":"1.98-android-11","data":{"state_data":{"states":[{"pid":2032,"value":"1"},{"pid":2043,"value":"0"},{"pid":2042,"value":"1"},{"pid":2044,"value":"0"},{"pid":2045,"value":"0"},{"pid":2048,"value":"0"},{"pid":2050}]},"tele_data":{"records":[{"lbs":{"ts":0,"mcc":0,"mnc":0,"list":[]},"wifi":{"ts":0,"list":[]},"onlyRefreshState":true,"ts":1613051720,"lat":30.0105213,"lon":31.5491452,"acc":7.886000156402588,"spd":0.08345689326524734,"seq":21978,"alarm_btn":false,"type":1,"bat":68,"ext_pwr":true}],"onlyRefreshState":true}}}
02-11 15:55:20.525   730  1056 I EDEN    : [Exynos][EDEN][v1.5.9][SERVICE] processAliveMointorMain:173: Try to check pid=(706)...
02-11 15:55:20.538 18543 18543 I wpa_supplicant: Heartbeat 3622
02-11 15:55:20.540 14878 14878 E ExpandableNotifRow: onNotificationUpdated() NSSL is null..
02-11 15:55:20.544 14878 14878 D swipe   : !isFreemformEnabled
02-11 15:55:20.546 14878 14878 D FaceWidgetNotificationManager: updateFaceWidgetMusicNotificationKey() return : mFaceWidgetMusicNotificationKey is empty
02-11 15:55:20.548 26759 26876 D ScanFilter: manu data matches
02-11 15:55:20.548 26759 26876 D BtGatt.GattService: onScanResult to scannerId: 17- eventType=0x1b, addressType=0, address=BB:F, primaryPhy=1, secondaryPhy=0, advertisingSid=0xff, txPower=127, rssi=-56, periodicAdvInt=0x0
02-11 15:55:20.549 21245 21971 I [+2]oneconnect[1.7.60.23_01][CORE]: BleParserForVD.parseTvPacket - (Extention)[Name]($)-[(26)[DeviceType]UNKNOWN[Discover]_BLE[Services]None[Connected]false[Type]6[Index]1[TvStatus]32[TvService]103[TvMirrorChannel]0[TvRegisteredDB]null[TvYear]2019[TvOcfInfo]15[TvAcmStatus]0[ExTvStatus]0
02-11 15:55:20.551 26759 26876 D ScanFilter: manu data matches
02-11 15:55:20.551 26759 26876 D BtGatt.GattService: onScanResult to scannerId: 17- eventType=0x1b, addressType=0, address=BB:F, primaryPhy=1, secondaryPhy=0, advertisingSid=0xff, txPower=127, rssi=-56, periodicAdvInt=0x0
02-11 15:55:20.551 21245 21971 I [+2]oneconnect[1.7.60.23_01][CORE]: BleParserForVD.parseTvPacket - (Extention)[Name]($)-[(26)[DeviceType]UNKNOWN[Discover]_BLE[Services]None[Connected]false[Type]6[Index]1[TvStatus]32[TvService]103[TvMirrorChannel]0[TvRegisteredDB]null[TvYear]2019[TvOcfInfo]15[TvAcmStatus]0[ExTvStatus]0
02-11 15:55:20.573 26759 26876 D ScanFilter: manu data matches
02-11 15:55:20.573 26759 26876 D BtGatt.GattService: onScanResult to scannerId: 17- eventType=0x1b, addressType=0, address=BB:F, primaryPhy=1, secondaryPhy=0, advertisingSid=0xff, txPower=127, rssi=-56, periodicAdvInt=0x0
02-11 15:55:20.574 21245 21971 I [+2]oneconnect[1.7.60.23_01][CORE]: BleParserForVD.parseTvPacket - [Name]($)-[(26)[DeviceType]TV[Discover]_BLE[Services]_TvSoundToMobile[Connected]false[TvStatus]1[TvService]103[TvMirrorChannel]1[TvRegisteredDB][-48, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0][TvYear]2016[TvOcfInfo]0[TvAcmStatus]0[ExTvStatus]0
02-11 15:55:20.577 26759 26876 D ScanFilter: manu data matches
02-11 15:55:20.577 26759 26876 D BtGatt.GattService: onScanResult to scannerId: 17- eventType=0x1b, addressType=0, address=BB:F, primaryPhy=1, secondaryPhy=0, advertisingSid=0xff, txPower=127, rssi=-57, periodicAdvInt=0x0
02-11 15:55:20.578 21245 21971 I [+2]oneconnect[1.7.60.23_01][CORE]: BleParserForVD.parseTvPacket - [Name]($)-[(26)[DeviceType]TV[Discover]_BLE[Services]_TvSoundToMobile[Connected]false[TvStatus]1[TvService]103[TvMirrorChannel]1[TvRegisteredDB][-48, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0][TvYear]2016[TvOcfInfo]0[TvAcmStatus]0[ExTvStatus]0
02-11 15:55:20.610 14475 17719 D OomAdjuster: uidRec.curCapability changed uid=10270 from 0 to 0
02-11 15:55:20.610 14475 17719 D OomAdjuster: uidRec.curCapability changed uid=10270 from 0 to 0
02-11 15:55:20.611 18647 18680 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
02-11 15:55:20.611 18647 18680 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
02-11 15:55:20.612 14289 14359 E Netd    : getNetworkForDns: getNetId from enterpriseCtrl is netid 0
02-11 15:55:20.613 14287 14622 I CameraService: notifyMonitoredUids
02-11 15:55:20.618 18647 18681 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
02-11 15:55:20.619 18647 18681 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
02-11 15:55:20.619 14289 14359 E Netd    : getNetworkForDns: getNetId from enterpriseCtrl is netid 0
02-11 15:55:20.627 14475 17719 D NetdEventListenerService: DNS Requested by : 610, 10287
02-11 15:55:20.627 18647 18680 D TcpOptimizer: TcpOptimizer-ON
02-11 15:55:20.628 14475 17719 D NetdEventListenerService: DNS Requested by : 610, 10287
02-11 15:55:20.646 14475 16986 I GenerationRegistry: mBackingStore.isClosed() : false
02-11 15:55:20.668   646   646 E audit   : type=1300 audit(1613051720.664:69881): arch=c00000b7 syscall=56 success=yes exit=57 a0=ffffff9c a1=79e431d270 a2=80000 a3=0 items=0 ppid=14284 pid=18647 auid=4294967295 uid=10287 gid=10287 euid=10287 suid=10287 fsuid=10287 egid=10287 sgid=10287 fsgid=10287 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="Thread-4" exe="/system/bin/app_process64" subj=u:r:untrusted_app_29:s0:c31,c257,c512,c768 key=(null)
02-11 15:55:20.668   646   646 E audit   : type=1327 audit(1613051720.664:69881): proctitle="com.truecaller"
02-11 15:55:20.668   646   646 E audit   : type=1300 audit(1613051720.664:69882): arch=c00000b7 syscall=56 success=yes exit=65 a0=ffffff9c a1=79e431d270 a2=80000 a3=0 items=0 ppid=14284 pid=18647 auid=4294967295 uid=10287 gid=10287 euid=10287 suid=10287 fsuid=10287 egid=10287 sgid=10287 fsgid=10287 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="Thread-4" exe="/system/bin/app_process64" subj=u:r:untrusted_app_29:s0:c31,c257,c512,c768 key=(null)
02-11 15:55:20.668   646   646 E audit   : type=1327 audit(1613051720.664:69882): proctitle="com.truecaller"
02-11 15:55:20.674 14475 16986 I GenerationRegistry: mBackingStore.isClosed() : false
02-11 15:55:20.681 18647 18702 I DynamiteLoaderV2Impl: [71] Measurementdynamite
02-11 15:55:20.704 18647 18647 E HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: Failed to find HMS apk
02-11 15:55:20.723 18647 18733 I FA      : App measurement initialized, version: 38002
02-11 15:55:20.723 18647 18733 I FA      : To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
02-11 15:55:20.723 18647 18733 I FA      : To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
02-11 15:55:20.723 18647 18733 I FA      :   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.truecaller
02-11 15:55:20.723 15760 15777 W ProviderHelper: Unknown dynamite feature providerinstaller
02-11 15:55:20.726 18647 18738 I com.truecaller: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
02-11 15:55:20.731 14475 17719 W ActivityManager: Background start not allowed: service Intent { cmp=com.truecaller/.calling.clipboard.ClipboardService } to com.truecaller/.calling.clipboard.ClipboardService from pid=18647 uid=10287 pkg=com.truecaller startFg?=false
02-11 15:55:20.731  8650  8650 I System.out:  === SERVER REPLY: {"result":0,"data":{"config":{"objectCode":222082,"lastParent":{"title":"+201006052154","ts":1608292642308},"logging":false,"enableBuzzer":false,"checkinPeriod":60}}}
02-11 15:55:20.732 16165 16213 I GpsSession_FLP: State[POSTURE] is changed to FACE_UP
02-11 15:55:20.737 18647 18738 I com.truecaller: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
02-11 15:55:20.738 14475 16986 D PackageManager: setEnabledSetting : userId = 0 packageName = com.truecaller cmp = androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService newState = 1 callingPackage = 10287/com.truecaller
02-11 15:55:20.741 18647 18647 I TetheringManager: registerTetheringEventCallback:com.truecaller
02-11 15:55:20.741 18647 18647 D ConnectivityManager: ConnectivityManager() mContext=com.truecaller.TrueApp@f7210ba getOpPackageName()=com.truecaller getBasePackageName()=com.truecaller getPackageName()=com.truecaller
02-11 15:55:20.748 14475 16986 D OomAdjuster: uidRec.curCapability changed uid=10270 from 0 to 0
02-11 15:55:20.748 14475 16986 D OomAdjuster: uidRec.curCapability changed uid=10270 from 0 to 0
02-11 15:55:20.766 14475 16986 D PackageManager: setEnabledSetting : userId = 0 packageName = com.truecaller cmp = com.truecaller.TruecallerInitAlias newState = 1 callingPackage = 10287/com.truecaller
02-11 15:55:20.769 14475 16986 D PackageManager: setEnabledSetting : userId = 0 packageName = com.truecaller cmp = com.truecaller.DialerActivityAlias newState = 1 callingPackage = 10287/com.truecaller
02-11 15:55:20.786 18647 18738 V NativeCrypto: Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 287 native methods...
02-11 15:55:20.791 14475 16986 I ClientCertificateManager Service: ClientCertificateManager.isPremiumContainer() : false for user : 0
02-11 15:55:20.792 14475 17949 D PackageManager: setEnabledSetting : userId = 0 packageName = com.truecaller cmp = com.truecaller.incallui.service.InCallUIService newState = 2 callingPackage = 10287/com.truecaller
```

My buildozer.spec:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Password Generator

# (str) Package name
package.name = pwssgen

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.passwordgen

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,db,java

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.16

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,sqlite3,pyjnius,kivmob,android

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 29

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 24

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
android.add_src = %(source.dir)s/org/fingerprint/*.java

# (list) Android AAR archives to add
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add
android.gradle_dependencies = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_packaging_options =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
android.meta_data = com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID={ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713}

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (str) Android additional adb arguments
#android.adb_args = -H host.docker.internal

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = arm64-v8a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
android.allow_backup = True

# (str) XML file for custom backup rules (see official auto backup documentation)
# android.backup_rules =

# (str) If you need to insert variables into your AndroidManifest.xml file,
# you can do so with the manifestPlaceholders property.
# This property takes a map of key-value pairs. (via a string)
# Usage example : android.manifest_placeholders = [myCustomUrl:\"org.kivy.customurl\"]
# android.manifest_placeholders = [:]

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =

# Control passing the --use-setup-py vs --ignore-setup-py to p4a
# "in the future" --use-setup-py is going to be the default behaviour in p4a, right now it is not
# Setting this to false will pass --ignore-setup-py, true will pass --use-setup-py
# NOTE: this is general setuptools integration, having pyproject.toml is enough, no need to generate
# setup.py if you're using Poetry, but you need to add "toml" to source.include_exts.
#p4a.setup_py = false


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
ios.codesign.allowed = false

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to remove the # from android.logcat_filters